# You are installing software that contains unsigned content While installing ADT plugin

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting this error while installing ADT plugin.

[image]

How can I solve this issue?
If I click on ok button plugins are getting installed but When I create new Eclipse project It creating project with blank folders, also it is not creating files like androidManifest.xml

Comment: What makes you think that the "unsigned content" warning is what is causing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occur when you install the plugin on the Eclipse, or when you execute an update?
What version of sdk and eclipse has installed?

Comment: Eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 2.

Comment: It occurs when I install ADT plugin.

Comment: And updating with the ADT Manager?

Comment: Downloaded some version of Android?